# sqlite3 3.5.7 vs. 3.6.21 brackets issue

Tags: python, windows, linux, sqlite, brackets

I am writing a python (2.7) script which executes a sqlite3 query. I am testing this query on a windows computer and it works like a charm. When I switch on Linux the query fails. it gives an error: it cannot find such a column... (i.e. tableA.ID wich exists obviously and it has no typos)

The query is basically a sequence of left join that creates a flat table.

It is in the format:

```
 select tableA.fieldA,tableA.fieldB, tableB.fieldC etc... 
 from ((tableA LEFT JOIN tableB on tableA.ID = tableB.FID) LEFT JOIN tableC on tableA.ID = tableC.FID) etc...
```

this kind of query works on windows but fails on linux with that error unless I remove the brackets on linux like this:

```
 select tableA.fieldA,tableA.fieldB, tableB.fieldC etc... 
 from tableA LEFT JOIN tableB on tableA.ID = tableB.FID LEFT JOIN tableC on tableA.ID = tableC.FID etc...
```

in this case it does not give the error and executes the query.
now the only different thing between the two systems beside the operating system is:

```
 (from python)
 >>>import sqlite3
 >>>sqlite3.sqlite_version 
 '3.5.7' (this is on linux)
 >>>sqlite3.sqlite_version 
 '3.6.21' (this is on windows)
```

what is different between those two versions and how can i make the code work on linux (using parenthesis possibly)?
it's very hard to tell if the result of the query without brackets can be trusted and whether it is the same as the one with, since it's a huge amount of data and would require long tests before making sure everything is ok.

EDIT: how does a LEFT JOIN works without brackets? will be first joined left most tables and then the rest? if I am sure the query would behave the same way without brakets I can go for it. i am grouping left joins from left most to rightmost, i.e.: (((((A B)C)D)E)F)

Comment: You might try looking through the SQLite [release history summary](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html).

Comment: at first glance left join will allow me to have the same behavior without brackets so i will stick with that for the time being. If I don't get major bugs won't bother me, since apparently nobody has a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend first harmonizing your sqlite3's on the two platforms so Linux and Windows are running the same version.  As of this writing (April 30, 2012) the current version is 3.7.11.  Downloads are available at http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

As a side note I find that the versions of code you get from the Linux distro's repository generally tend to be out of date so it is better to download from the software's web site directly.

Comment: Updating may not solve the Op problem, because he might need to support older versions of sqlite3, and thus he probably wants to make both work. Otherwise he must add a dependency on the version of sqlite3.